# crowd funding platform?

Tags: looking-for-a-script

I have been searching for days. Is there a good crowd funding framework that I could use as the base for a project? Something like a kickstarter clone in Ruby on Rails or PHP?

There are one or two out there, but they look terrible.

Comment: What's wrong with using Kickstarter itself?

Comment: its for internal/private uses hosted on the intranet of the organization I work with

Comment: Hmm...now I'm interested in why you need to get employees of your company to fund the projects your company is working on?

Comment: Because they get "brownie" points, and can use their "brownie" points for their favorite internal cause. I need to modify the platform so that instead of USDs they use "brownie" points, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Co-creator of http://ignitiondeck.com here. We wanted something we could put into use quickly for our own projects, so we built ID on top of WordPress as a plugin. We asked the very same question and saw very little, but I'd love to hear if you find something, as I believe the need definitely exists.

Answer (score 2):

From what you mention in your comment it sounds like a bug-tracking system could be the way to go. I know that the [KDE Bug Tracker](https://bugs.kde.org) uses exactly the system you mentioned of "votes" to apportion to bugs/features.

However, I can't find if their software is available to download and self-host. Perhaps check some other similar software like Bugzilla and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Well I checked a few out after reading Somid3's response to you Goat and couldn't find anything that had a voting feature built into it, Trac, Redmine, Bugzilla, Mantis and a few others... surprisingly I couldn't find a plugin or default function built into any of them.

Comment: yeah, open source lacks in this feature set

Answer (score 1):

As DisgruntledGoat said, Kickstarter.  But there is also [RocketHub](http://rockethub.com/), [IndieGoGo](http://www.indiegogo.com/) and [Invested.in](http://invested.in/).

But I almost get the impression you are looking for something you can host yourself?  If that's the case I did a quick search and came up with [IgnitionDeck](http://ignitiondeck.com/) though it doesn't seem to be publicly available yet.

Worst case scenario you throw up a PayPal donate button somewhere.

Ultimately though your best bet is to use an already existing service.  Why?  People are more likely to help fund your cause through a well known name like Kickstarter or RocketHub than to donate to you directly.  It gives your cause a sense of credibility unless you already have an established audience that trusts you.

Comment: thanks, yes, I meant a framework as an application that I could install in the intranet of my organization. Thanks for your suggestion.